# Sort of Binomial Expansion

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I was trying to find a general formula for expanding the product: $$\prod_{i=1}^k (a+ib)$$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. The first few expansions are as follows: $$\prod_{i=1}^1 (a+ib) = a + b$$ $$\prod_{i=1}^2 (a+ib) = a^2+3ab+2b^2$$ $$\prod_{i=1}^3 (a+ib) = a^3 +6a^2b +11ab^2 +6b^3$$ At the time, I thought that there may be a connection between this product and the binomial expansion. I still think I am correct in thinking this. However, my combinatorial skills are not up to par. Anyways, I found a recursive formula that can generate the coefficients of the expansion. To steal from classical binomial coefficient notation, let  $\binom{0}{0} = 1$, $\binom{1}{0} = 1$, $\binom{1}{1} = 1$, and $\binom{k}{-1} = 0$, with $k\ge0$ be the initial values and have  $$\binom{n}{k} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k}$$ be the definition of this symbol during this question. Notice that this is very similar (but **not identical**) to the recursive definition of the original binomial expansion, which leads to all sorts of great mathematical fun. With this new knowledge and notation, I easily got the expansion. It is $$\prod_{i=1}^k (a+ib) =\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i}a^{k-i}b^i.$$ This is a pretty formula but I would feel better if I knew more than just the recursive definition. Help!!! So the question is this: How can I obtain a non-recursive definition from this?

I found out how cool this recursive definition is by replacing the traditional binomial coefficients with their corresponding "pseudo-binomial coefficients" (bad name, I know) on Pascal's Triangle.

I sort of feel bad for not proving any of the things I said here, but hopefully you will forgive me after you search for all the pretty patterns that come up when you inspect this new sort of triangle! I also doubt that I am the first one to think of this, so it would be great if someone had information on this stuff. (I have not found any information on it, but I didn't try very hard sooo...)Thank you so much in advanced for your patience and your diligence!

Comment: An alternative form: $\Pi_{i=1}^k(a+ib)=b^k\Gamma(\frac{a}{b}+k+1)/\Gamma(\frac{a}{b}+1).$

Comment: **This is a pretty formula** - It is indeed. It is also wrong. In case you haven't noticed, all its terms, save for the last one, are $0$, making your product $b^k$.

Comment: @Lucian I don't see how you came to this conclusion. I am sure that what you say is incorrect. Please look over it again and if you still think this then explain why I am incorrect. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: *i* goes from $0$ to *k*, correct ? So it is always smaller than *k* from $0$ to $k-1$, and then equal to it when $i=k$. Now, ${a\choose b}=0$ for integer values of *a* and *b* when $a<b$. I've also checked it with *Mathematica*, just to make sure. And even if you meant to write $k\choose i$, then it's $(a+b)^k$, which is different from the product in question.

Comment: @Lucian You have confused the symbol that I used with the real binomial expansion. The real binomial expansion has the definition $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k}$. However what I used is not this. Your confusion is understandable however because I didn't make clear enough that the sign that is meant for the binomial coefficients has another meaning here. Thank you for your feedback. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Well, in that case, congratulations, you have just rediscovered [Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) three centuries after [Lord Stirling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Stirling_(mathematician)). They are usually symbolized by square brackets, $\bigg[\begin{align}a\\b\end{align}\bigg]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that:
$$\begin{align}\prod_{i=1}^{k}(a+i b) & = b^k\prod_{i=1}^{k}(\tfrac a b + i) \\ & = b^k(\tfrac a b +1)(\tfrac a b +2)\cdots(\tfrac a b + k)\end{align}$$
Now *if* $\tfrac ab$ were an integer, say $n$, then we would have: $$b^k\prod_{i=1}^k(n+i)= \frac{(n+k)!\,b^k}{n!}$$
Now the factorial function can be *extended* to real (and complex) arguments, through the **complete gamma function**.
$$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{z-1}\operatorname{d}t$$
And for natural number arguments: $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$
So what we have is:$$\prod_{i=1}^k (a+i b) = \frac{b^k \Gamma(\tfrac ab + k+1)}{\Gamma(\tfrac ab+1)}$$
This ratio occurs often enough to be given a symbol: **Pochhammer**, and it's summation expansion is:
$$(x)_k=\frac{\Gamma(x+k)}{\Gamma(x)}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (-1)^{k-i}\operatorname{s}(k,i)x^i$$
Where $\operatorname{s}(k,i)$ is a **Stirrling number of the first kind**, which is defined by the recurrence relation:
 $$\begin{align}
\operatorname{s}(k+1,i) & = \operatorname{s}(k,i-1) - k \operatorname{s}(k,i), &\text{ for }1\leq i\leq k 
\\ \operatorname{s}(k,i)&=\sum_{j=i}^k k^{j-i} \operatorname{s}(k+1,i+1),&\text{ for } i\geq 1
\\ \binom{i}{r}\operatorname{s}(k,i)&=\sum_{j=i-r}^{n-r}\binom{k}{j}\operatorname{s}(k-j,r)\operatorname{s}(j,i-r),&\text{ for }0\leq r \leq i
\end{align}$$ 
And... well, that should give you a start for further research topics.